# Analytic continuation of power series of holomorphic with real nonnegative coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, power-series, analytic-continuation

Consider a holomorphic function $f(z)$ defined as power series $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n},$$ with radius of convergence $R=1$.

I want to show that

> If $a_{n}\geq 0$ for all $n$, then $f(z)$ cannot be analytically continued to $1\in \partial\mathbb{D}$.

---

I don't quite have an idea about where to start. As the exercise supposes $a_{n}\geq 0$ for all $n$, it means that the exercise also implicitly assumes that $a_{n}\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $n$.

From the radius of convergence, I know that $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}^{\frac{1}{n}}=1\ \ \text{and}\ \ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}=1.$$ (I get rid of the norm because $a_{n}$ is real and non-negative.)

Suppose $f(z)$ can be analytically continued to $1\in\partial\mathbb{D}$, then it means that there exists a $r=r(1)>0$ such that there exists a holomorphic function $g(z)$ on $B(1,r)$  such that $g(z)=f(z)$ on $B(1,r)\cap\mathbb{D}$.

But then I don't know how to proceed..

I tried to argue that if I define $h(z):=f(z)$ for $z\in\mathbb{D}$ and $h(z):=g(z)$ for $z\in B(1,r)$, then $h(z)$ is holomorphic in the whole $\mathbb{D}\cup B(1,r)$, so it has a power expansion $$h(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}z^{n},$$ and in particular, at $z=1$, we must have $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}<\infty.$$

But it seems no way to get back to $f(z)$. What should I do? Thank you!

Comment: Try to show that being continuable at 1 for such coefficients implies that $f$ is continuable at each point on the disc.

Comment: the coolest way to do this is to use that $f^{(k)}(c) \ge 0, 0 \le c <1$ (why?) and that $|f^{(k)}(e^{it}c)| \le f^{(k)}(c)$ (why?); this implies that the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $f$ at any $0 \le c <1$ is lower or equal to the radius of convergence at $e^{it}c$ (why?) so in particular if said radius at some $c$ is strictly bigger than $1-c$ (which follows for $c \to 1$ by the assumption of extension at $1$, it follows same on the full circle of radius $c$, hence $f$ would be extendable on the full unit circle and that is not possible by radius convergence $1$

Comment: @Conrad okay I will work on it following your suggestion, will be back soon :) Thanks for always helping me in such a good way :)))

Comment: Perhaps show that $f$ has an essential singularity at $z=1$? Indeed, showing $f(z)$ is unbounded as $z \to 1$ should suffice.

Comment: @copper the issue is that $f$ may not be unbounded at $1$ (see $\sum z^n/n^2$ which is not continuable at $1$ for the simple fact that the derivative isn't - however examples can be given where all the derivatives converge at $1$, coefficients non negative and still the function is not continuable

Comment: @Conrad Sorry, don't know what I was thinking. (Well, I do, but it was really silly.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $f$ is analytic at $1$, since everything is increasing $$f^{(k)}(1)=\lim_{z\to 1^-}f^{(k)}(z)= \lim_{z\to 1^-} \sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} z^{n-k}=\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$$
Next we are told that for any $s>0$ $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (1+s)^n= \infty$$
Everything is non-negative so we can change the order of summation as we want obtaining
$$\infty=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \sum_{k=0}^n s^k\frac{ n!}{k!(n-k)!}  = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{s^k}{k!} \sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n\frac{n! }{(n-k)!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{s^k}{k!} f^{(k)}(1)$$
contradicting that $f$ is analytic at $1$.

Comment: Nice manipulation and the conclusion using Taylor series. Thank you!